# set -x doesn't print stack info for bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In my `bash 4.2.46 and centos - 7.1.1503`, I ran `set -x` (to print debug info). Now, if I type `ls`, it prints:

```
+ ls --color=auto
a    b   c
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' root sk-vbox '~'
```

All well and happy. But when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> on a shell variable for completion, it prints output without stack info:

```
echo $HO  #tab key press here
```

gives:

```
$HOME      $HOSTNAME  $HOSTTYPE
```

and zero lines of stack info.

I need this stack information badly to debug an issue in which bash puts extra space on autocompletion (similar to [acroread issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866/comments/7%20b) but possibly due to a different reason since `/etc/bash_completion.d` doesn't contain the culprit, `acroread.sh` in my case.)

I'm using bash 4.2.46 on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your operating system and bash version. I can't reproduce this on Debian and bash v4.3.33. Hitting tab does print the stack info.

Comment: bash - `4.2.46` and centos -  `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503`. I tried upgrading to the newest bash in the town, but `yum update bash` replies `No packages marked for update`. so i am struck with `4.2.46`

Comment: Are you sure you have configurable completion active in that shell, and not the built-in stuff? If you run `bash --norc`, you get the built-in stuff, which executes to bash code so prints no trace. You need to source `/etc/bash_completion` to get the configurable completion. Does e.g. `rpm -q` complete package names or files?